# prove that the following sequence's limit is 2

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let the sequence $a_n $ have exactly two partial limits (limits of all of its subsequences).
>
> The two partial limits are $3$ and $-1$.
>
> Let $b_n = |a_n-1|$, for all $n\in \Bbb N$.
>
> Prove that $ \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} b_n = 2$

How would you prove such a claim, i am guessing it has to do with $3+(-1) = 2$, or somthing else to do with those two partial limits,
but I wouldn't know how to prove that.
Could anyone tip me on how to prove that?

Comment: sorry for that, i added the actual limits

Comment: Do you know that $\left|\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}(x_n)\right|=\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(|x_n|\right)$?

Comment: i do now, but how do i connect that the the limit of the subsequences?

Comment: Is my hint enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Any sequence converges to $l$, if, and only if, all of its subsequences converge to $l$.

**Further details:**
Let $(b_{n_k})_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be any subsequence of $(b_{n})_{n\in \Bbb N}$. The following holds: 
$$\begin{align} \lim \limits_{k\to +\infty}\left(b_{n_k}\right)&=\lim \limits_{k\to +\infty}\left(|a_{n_k}-1|\right)\\ &=\left|\lim \limits_{k\to +\infty}\left(a_{n_k-1}\right)\right|\\ &=\left|\lim \limits_{k\to +\infty}(a_{n_k})-1\right|\\ &=\begin{cases}|3-1|, &\text{if }\lim \limits_{k\to +\infty}(a_{n_k})=3\\|-1-1|, &\text{if } \lim \limits_{k\to +\infty}(a_{n_k})=-1\end{cases}\\ &=2\end{align}$$

Comment: So then we'll say that: $limb_{n_k}=|-1-1|=2$ 

And

$limb_{n_k}=|3-1|=2$

So $limb_{n}=2$ ?

Comment: @GinKin Not quite. 'And' should be 'or'.

Comment: Or yes, two different cases. We never used this though: $\left|\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}(x_n)\right|=\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(|x_n|\right)$

Comment: I don't know but $limb_{n_k}=|a_{n_k}-1|$. Or maybe this has something to do with the triangle inequality ?

Comment: @GinKin I added some details. It should now become apparent where the above fact is used.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice.

Comment: @GinKin You understanding the problem is appreciation enough.